# php pdo insert to column with question mark in name

Tags: php, pdo

I spent few hours trying to insert a query using PDO, and finally I realized that I can`t do it (dont know how).
The problem is in fact that column name have "?" in it. One of columns is named "If HSM Visa to what year?". Because of that, Every time I do insert I get either: 
- wrong number of parameters passed or
- cant mix name and ? in query.

I gave up from this, and I'm going to alter mysql table I got to work with (who is naming columns with question marks anyway ?), but I'm still curious.

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_maindetails` (`Id`,`Title`,`If HSM Visa to what year?`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Thanks,
Goran

Comment: Sounds like you may have discovered a bug in PDO since you appear to have correctly quoted your column names in the query - I'd go an [raise a bug report](https://bugs.php.net/). But like you say having a column name with a question mark in it sounds like a poor DB design and renaming the column is the actual answer to the problem here.

Comment: I agree with @DaveRandom. I would recommend only using numbers, letters, or dashes (staying away from underscores) in column names.

Comment: No help with that. \? Dont do anything.
If anyone finds a solution, I`ll be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
```

will solve the issue, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem!  I tried to get around the confusion between the character "?" in the column (field) names and the same character "?" as a positional (un-named) placeholder in PDO, by switching to NAMED parameter binding... but the problem STILL persists :(

Now, PDO sees the "?" in the column names and thinks I'm mixing up named and positional parameters!

For example:

```
UPDATE myTable SET `title` = :title, `Underwater?` = :Underwater 
WHERE ID='123'
```

together with the following binding:

```
 Array ( [:title] => test  [:Underwater] => 0)
```

produces thee following ERROR MESSAGE:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters"
```

Notice that I avoided placing any "?" inside the placeholder itself (it's **":Underwater"** rather than **":Underwater?"**, but it was no help...)

Clearly, this is a bug!  PDO is seeing the "?" in the column names, and jumping to the conclusion that it's a positional placeholder, even if we are strictly using NAME parameter binding!

I'll see if I can report this bug...

Since MySQL allows question marks in the column names, I see no compelling reason why we must avoid them!  (Though, in the short term, I'll do that, sigh...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only (ugly) solution that I could come up with:

```
$db->query("SET @column_name = 'question?'");
$db->query("SET @sql_text = CONCAT('INSERT INTO table1 SET `', @column_name, '` = ?')");
$db->query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;");
$db->query("SET @v = ?", 'something');
$db->query("EXECUTE stmt USING @v");
echo $db->insert_id();
```

This will insert a new row into table1 with question? = 'something'

This code is using a PDO wrapper so you'll need to adjust for that.

In the long run I think you made the right choice by renaming the column.